# -[UINavigationController selectedViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x105ca6000

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (BOOL)tabBarIsVisible {
   UIViewController *vc =  ((MSTabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController).selectedViewController;
   return self.tabBarC.tabBar.frame.origin.y < CGRectGetMaxY(vc.view.frame);
}
```

I am adding this in app delegate and checking when app enters background.

Comment: It's because `self.window.rootViewController` is navigation controller.

Comment: show more of your code, as to what is set as root in your window etc. i'm guessing your referenced viewController is not what your expecting so there is a class mismatch.